# Collision.impulse handing back zero sometimes

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

Collision.impulse is not handing back high numbers as usual but it's handing back zero sometimes, here's my code and some screenshots.

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    float collision_force = collision.impulse.magnitude / Time.fixedDeltaTime;
    Debug.Log(collision_force);
    if(!explosion_sound_normal.isPlaying() && collision_force > 7000f)
    {
        explosion_sound_normal.Play();
    }
}
```

[Game](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBrem.jpg)

Comment: Does the vehicle have a Rigidbody and Collider component attached? As well as the terrain having a collider? You could also try moving the size of the Vector outside of the calculation, using `float collision_force = (collision.impulse / Time.fixedDeltaTime).magnitude;`

Comment: Yes my car has both a collider and a rigidbody.